# How to extract substring between patterns "_" and "." in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have many filenames which look like:

```
txt= "MA0051_IRF2.xml"
```

I want to extract `IRF2` which is between "_" and ".". How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To achieve this, you need a regexp that

- matches an (optional) arbitrary string in front of the _ : `.*`
- matches a literal _ : `[_]`
- matches everything up to (but not including) the next . and stores it in capturing group no. 1 : `([^.]+)`
- matches a literal . :  `[.]`
- matches an (optional) arbitrary string after the . : `.*`

In your call to gsub, you then

- use the regular expression we built in the previous step
- replace the whole string with the contents of the first capturing group: `\\1` (we need to escape the backslash, hence the double backslash)

**Example:**

```
gsub(".*[_]([^.]+)[.].*", "\\1", "MA0051_IRF2.xml")
```

Comment: excellent explanation! Could you please explain what "\\1" does in gsub()?

Comment: `_` isn't special and doesn't need to be escaped or put in a character class.  +1 for `[.]`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg You're right about the _, of course.

Comment: what if txt= "MA0051_IRF2.xml  MA0051_IRF3.xml". I need IRF2 ans IRF3.

Answer (score 6):

an other possibility with the stringr package:

```
 str_extract(x, perl("(?<=_)(.+)(?=\\.)"))
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, current versions of `stringr` do not longer use the function `perl`, the syntax for stringr v>1.4 would be `str_extract(x, "(?<=_)(.+)(?=\\.)")`.

Answer (score 4):

```
gsub(".*_(.*)\\..*", "\\1", txt)
##"IRF2"
```

Comment: why do you escape underscore ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution that doesn't require regex knowledge:

```
txt <- "MA0051_IRF2.xml"

library(qdap)
genXtract(txt, "_", ".")

## _  :  . 
##  "IRF2"
```

Comment: This is cool, but you can make sure you can extract as a character to add it in mutate? For example `mutate(extract=genXtract(txt,"-",".")`