# How to extract a substring between ambiguous symbols in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a vector of data in R that has entries like `data = BURR_WK_94_91`and I want to extract the number that falls between the two underscores. So in this case get 94. The strings are of variable length so I can't use a starting position.

I'm almost there with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518325/how-to-extract-substring-between-symbol-and) answer

```
library(qdap)
genXtract(data, "_", "_")
```

But that gives me extra data that I don't need. Is there a way to query if the string is a number between the underscores then extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use:

```
gsub(".*_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", "BURR_WK_94_91", perl = T)

(\\d+) - denotes a capture group - capture any number of digits 
\\1 - back reference to the first capture group
.*_ - any number of characters ending with a _
_.* - any number of characters starting with a _
```

So basically what you telling the function to do is to replace everything with the capture group.

if there is exactly 2 digits:

```
 gsub(".*_(\\d{2})_.*", "\\1", "BURR_WK_94_91", perl = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example using lookbehind and lookahead with regex.

```
data = "BURR_WK_94_91"
gsub(".*(?<=_)(\\d+)(?=_).*", "\\1", data, perl = TRUE)

[1] "94"
```

Or, using `stringr` package, you only have to match the exact group.

```
stringr::str_extract_all(data, "(?<=_)((\\d+)*)(?=_)")

[[1]]
[1] "94"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_match from the stringr package

```
stringr::str_match(data, "_([0-9]{2})_") %>%
  magrittr::extract(,2)
```