# R - gsub() : trouble when trying to extract a string between ". " and "_"

Tags: r, delimiter, gsub

The R gsub() syntax is so difficult to me ! Could you, please, help me to extract, for example, "DA VINCI" from "16. DA VINCI_RETOUR" ?

I've already tried `gsub("_.+$", "", x)` but it just removes what is after the "_" and I would like also to remove what is before the ". " !

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Could you show the failed attempt? It might help you to better understand what went wrong.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/23518325/680068

Comment: I've already seen this post but it didn't help me at all ! Thank you @zx8754 ! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` takes everything at the beginning, `\\.` matches `.`, (.*) matches everything until and stores it in `\\1` `_` and `.*` removes the rest.

```
x  <- "16. DA VINCI_RETOUR"
sub(".*\\. (.*)_.*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "DA VINCI"

x  <- "7. TILLEUL_RETOUR"
sub(".*\\. (.*)_.*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "TILLEUL"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with capture group to match the pattern of word (`\\w+`) followed by space and another word as a group and replace with the backreference of the capture group (`\\1`)

```
sub("^\\d+\\.\\s+(\\w+\\s+\\w+)_.*", "\\1", str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "16. DA VINCI_RETOUR"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! It works perfectly on "16. DA VINCI_RETOUR" but when I try to use it on an other example like 7. TILLEUL_RETOUR your code doesn't work anymore ! :(

Comment: @sallyb Please check the pattern you showed int he example and in the new one.  IN the first there is `DA` followed by space. In the second one, there is not.  regex works with patterns

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that uses `strsplit`:

```
gsub("\\d+\\.\\s","",
      strsplit(the_string,"_")[[1]][1])
[1] "DA VINCI"
```

Data:

```
the_string <- "16. DA VINCI_RETOUR"
```